# Do I have to get an apple developer account to use Apple Health Kit Api for my react native app?

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-developer

I keep getting this error "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement" even though I added Health Kit to my capabilities on Xcode. Getting this error in the signings page on Xcode, "Failed to create provisioning profile"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Sqp.png).

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a real device or simulator?  Real devcies require you to register them and to do that you need a developer account.

Comment: No I'm using a simulator and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Register the device you are trying to test in the Test Devices item through your Apple Developer account.